# How to upgrade MySQL 5.0 to 5.5 with master-master replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, upgrade

I have to update 2 hosts with SUSE Linux Enterprise 11 from SP2 to SP3 which implies an update from MySQL 5.0.94 to 5.5.31.

The [release notes](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/11-SP3/#fate-314322) state:

> SLE 11 SP3 introduces the upgrade of the MySQL database to version
>   5.5. This upgrade involves a change of the database format and the database needs to be converted before MySQL can run again. Therefore
>   MySQL is not running directly after the upgrade. 
>   To migrate the MySQL
>   database, run following commands as root:
>
> touch /var/lib/mysql/.force_upgrade
>
> rcmysql restart

Now the tricky part is that both hosts are configured with a master-master replication. Read access should be possible during the update, write access is not needed. How do I do this?